# How to show a non-adjacent range in a published Google Sheets document?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm able to embed an adjacent range using the [`query`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?hl=en) parameter, but if I can't get it to work with non-adjacent ranges. Here are some of my attempts using a public link:

```
# This works. It shows column A
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS-vH8TLPDj64Xqm2DQaS4MKT13y9yu6Nz69cwEw-sd-VapPyG_iW4_nrs2XxpMEdN41hbrfb_SwA2c/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true&range=A:A

# None of these work. I'd like to see columns A and C
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS-vH8TLPDj64Xqm2DQaS4MKT13y9yu6Nz69cwEw-sd-VapPyG_iW4_nrs2XxpMEdN41hbrfb_SwA2c/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true&range=A:A,C:C

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS-vH8TLPDj64Xqm2DQaS4MKT13y9yu6Nz69cwEw-sd-VapPyG_iW4_nrs2XxpMEdN41hbrfb_SwA2c/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true&range={A:A,C:C}

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS-vH8TLPDj64Xqm2DQaS4MKT13y9yu6Nz69cwEw-sd-VapPyG_iW4_nrs2XxpMEdN41hbrfb_SwA2c/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true&range=query({A:A,C:C})

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS-vH8TLPDj64Xqm2DQaS4MKT13y9yu6Nz69cwEw-sd-VapPyG_iW4_nrs2XxpMEdN41hbrfb_SwA2c/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true&range=query(A:A,C:C)
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

### I do not think this is possible because if two non adjacent ranges were to be published together, Google Sheets would not know how to combine them:

- Shall they become adjacent skipping the ranges inbetween?
- Shall the distance between them be preserved?

Your best bet would be copy the ranges of interest into a new sheet and either arrange them together or leaving empty spaces inbetween - depending on your intention  - and then publish the new, preformatted sheet instead of the original one.